# How to make responsive highchart?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I created a bar chart with Highcharts and stored it in the column col-md-12 using bootstrap, I set the width of this chart so that it is 100%, but it's width even exceeds col-md-12.

[image]

here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="kanwil-report-kepuasan" style="width: 100%; min-height: 330px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

and the Highcharts code :

```
$('#kanwil-report-kepuasan').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            colors: ['#3498DB'],
            title: {
                text: 'Index Kepuasan Nasabah Berdasarkan Kanwil'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                 title: {
                    text: ' '
                }
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                 // tickPositioner: function() {
                 //        return [0,10];
                 //    },
                 gridLineWidth: 0,

                title: {
                    text: 'Persentase'
                }

            },
            credits:{
                enabled:false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Score',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: {!! json_encode($kanwil_index_data_kepuasan,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) !!}   
            }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this page on the highcharts documentation page, http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/responsive

But to quote:

> Since Highcharts 5.0 you can create responsive charts much the same
>   way you work with responsive web pages. A top-level option,
>   responsive, exists in the configuration.
>
> It lets you define a set of rules, each with a condition, for example
>   maxWidth: 500, and a separate set of chartOptions that is applied on
>   top of the general chart options. The chartOptions work as overrides
>   to the regular chart options, which apply when the rule applies. For
>   example, the following rule will hide the legend for charts less than
>   500 pixels wide:

```
responsive: {
  rules: [{
    condition: {
      maxWidth: 500
    },
    chartOptions: {
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like the Highcharts chart is appearing in a tab that may not be visible when the page is first viewed.

Highcharts, and Javascript and jQuery in general, have challenges rendering objects to a correct width and height if they are first hidden and then made visible after the page loads. Javascript, etc. doesn't (reliably) hold width and height values of invisible objects, and not having that information interferes with the native responsiveness of Highcharts' code.

To get your chart to show with the correct dimensions, I'd suggest adding a click event on your tabs so that, whenever the tab showing the chart is shown, it captures the current size (width and height) of the "kanwil-report-kepuasan" div and then renders the chart **at that time** (not simply after the page has been loaded).

Here's how this would roughly work:

```
$("#TabThatHasChart").on('click',function(e){

    /* OPTIONAL: some variables you can use in your chart options for custom sizing */
    var chartWidth = $("#kanwil-report-kepuasan").width();
    var chartHeight = $("#kanwil-report-kepuasan").height();

    /* draw the chart once the tab has been clicked and it is now visible */
    $('#kanwil-report-kepuasan').highcharts({
        /* your chart options go here */
    });

    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

I hope this information is helpful for you.